# I can't make text disappear in Slider Revolution (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, revolution-slider

i want to make a specific part of my text layer change with time. For example, I want the first text to appear as "Get your T-shirts"
[first instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap8B9.png)
and then after 3000ms I want the "tshirts" to change to "pants". So, the next text would be "Get your pants". 
[second instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfrGj.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far, please edit your question to include code examples. Pictures of Text do not help people to understand your question, I would suggest that you remove them.

Comment: It's solved now. Thanks. You don't need to code anything, it can all be done within the app